# Is elon musks car in space getting over heated being in the sun?

Tags: spacex

Is the car elon musk put in space getting hot being in the sun?

Comment: Heat works differently in space, it's radiant. AFAIK his car is half hot half freezing.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn  Ah, so it's like a Chevy.

Comment: my ex girlfriend

Comment: I don't know what overheated means in this context.

Comment: So basically the parts that are in direct sunlight get pretty hot and the parts in shade get pretty cold. The hot bits are about 250F and the cold parts are well below freezing.

Comment: @uhoh: heated over the temperature allowed in manufacturer's specs.

Comment: @SF. I've posed the question for the OP with the idea that they can improve the question.